# Execute two VBA macros simultaenously

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Is it possible that 2 macros can be executed simultaneously in VBA.

So there will be one macro which will take inputs from a database in access and will continue to show the data like a news strip. That code I have made.

Now there are other data and charts also on the same sheet. The problem is can the user execute the other macros for changing the data/Charts on the same worksheet by pressing command buttons or selecting radio buttons while side by side the film strip like data continues to flow on the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be specific in your question. Is it about Excel VBA, or Access VBA? Remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Have two host processes running concurrently. Best you can get. You can't have one host process running 2+ VBA macros simultaneously, it's all running in a STA (single-threaded apartment) COM thread.

Comment: It is Excel VBA.The macro is in excel VBA. However the database is in access. i have linked excel with access database thorough ADO.

Comment: Well, can't you make a main program that call `Subs`? I made something similar on Excel with an OPC Server, where the user had to press buttons to call some subs. However, with access it can be different, because the dll from OPC Foundation has some usefull functions, like `Private Sub MyOPCGroup_DataChange()`

Comment: I fully agree with @Mat'sMug. If you're working with Access through VBA, you can even start up a worker Access Application object from your main thread, start up a form with a timer, and run your workload asynchronously on that timer, then close it afterwards. Wrap that functionality in a form and a class, and you can multithread fairly easily (I'm working on that btw, haven't got awaitables fully working yet).

Comment: Sounds like you want to show a banner while displaying excel sheet. Why not do this on a web page? that's what its designed for. You can use vb.net and have multi threading

Answer (score 2):

No. VBA is single-threaded. Thus, one task must complete before another can run.

You can fool it by using `Shell` to launch an external process, but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then is it possible that  the first macro continuously runs. Now when the user clicks to execute any other macro then the first one automatically stops and let the second macro run. After the second macro execution ends then the first macro automatically starts again.

Comment: @ANANDAGRAWAL Anything is possible...you would just need to have the first macro checking for a condition. Something like `If Not AnotherMacroIsWaitingToRun Then IWillKeepRunning`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Note that to keep the running macro from locking the thread, you will have to call `DoEvents` inside it often (every second or so) to keep it from locking the Excel application and keep you from actually starting the 2nd macro

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Agreed, one could also use `Application.Wait()` if the calling macro is just waiting. It does beg the question of "Why?" though, as in "Why is there a macro that needs to be running and running and running...until another macro can run."